# Как ввести данные Spring mvc 3 with Hibernate(и без Hibernate) из формы на базы данных через контроллер?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Service//("studentService")
@Transactional
public class StudentDAOServiceImpl implements StudentDAOService {


    @Autowired
    StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Student student) {
        studentDAO.add(student);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void edit(Student student) {
        studentDAO.edit(student);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(int studentId) {
        studentDAO.delete(studentId);

    }

    @Transactional
    public Student getStudent(int studentId) {  
        return studentDAO.getStudent(studentId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List getAllStudents() {    c
        return studentDAO.getAllStudents();
    }

}
```

Сделано только репозитории, формы и сервисы

---

```
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="userid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userid;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="userfam")
    private String userFam;

    @Column(name="userlogin")
    private String userLogin;

    @Column(name="userpass")
    private String userPass;

    @Column(name="useremail")
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name="userage")
    private int userAge;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userid = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserFam() {
        return userFam;
    }

    public void setUserFam(String userFam) {
        this.userFam = userFam;
    }

    public String getUserLogin() {
        return userLogin;
    }

    public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
    }

    public String getUserPass() {
        return userPass;
    }

    public void setUserPass(String userPass) {
        this.userPass = userPass;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUser")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userAdded") Users users, ModelMap modelMap) {  // ModelAndView
    modelMap.addAttribute("username", users.getUserName());
    modelMap.addAttribute("userfam", users.getUserFam());
    modelMap.addAttribute("userlogin", users.getUserLogin());
    modelMap.addAttribute("userpass", users.getUserPass());
    modelMap.addAttribute("useremail", users.getUserEmail());
    modelMap.addAttribute("userage", users.getUserAge());
    usersDAOService.insertUser(users);

    return "success";
}
```

---

> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.force.samples.dao.UsersDAOServiceIpml.insertUser(UsersDAOServiceIpml.java:21)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.insertUser(Unknown Source)
>     com.force.samples.controllers.HomeController.addUser(HomeController.java:104)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

---

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUser")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userAdded") Users users, ModelMap modelMap) { 

     usersDAOService.insertUser(users);

     return "success";
}
```

Comment: Просто контроллере из какого метода использовать я чуть не понял

Comment: Вместо того чтобы дополнять вопрос ответами используйте кнопку [edit].